# Computing $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\{x,y\}}^{1} e^{z^3} dz dx dy$

Tags: integration

I am trying to compute

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\{x,y\}}^{1} e^{z^3} dz dx dy$$

What I have done is to reverse the order of integration; so I did the integration with respect to $x$ and $y$ first.

I get this in the end:

$$\int_{\max\{x,y\}}^{1} e^{z^3} dz$$ which doesn't solve my problem.

Perhaps I am missing something. I'm not sure which values of $x$ and $y$ I have to look at (to take the maximum).

Note: This is not a homework problem - it's a practice question from my lectures which is not graded.

Comment: Maybe writing $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_{\max(x,y)}^1(\bullet)\,dzdydx=\int_0^1\int_x^1\int_y^1( \bullet )\,dzdydx+\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_x^1(\bullet)\,dzdydx$$ will help you understand what's wrong with what you've done.

Comment: Note that $z>\max\{x,y\}$ if and only if $x<z$ and $y<z$, hence $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\{x,y\}}^{1} e^{z^3} dz dx dy= 
\int_{0}^{1}e^{z^3}\left(\int_{0}^{z}\int_{0}^{z} dx dy\right) dz= 
\int_{0}^{1}z^2e^{z^3}dz=\ldots$$